# Angular filter table on checkbox value

Tags: html, angular, angular-material-table

I am trying to filter my table based on the value of a checkbox, the filter should be possible with a dropdown, which shows either all rows, rows where the checkbox is checked, and rows where the checkbox is not checked. I tried with :

```
<tr *ngFor="let step of steps | tableFilter: checked"></tr>
```

But I cant get it to work. I am tying on the example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwnnzf-penyen?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.html
Thanks!

Comment: cant open the link

Comment: Sorry! I edited it now

Comment: do you want to filter it via a pipe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter the table data based on selection, you can do this by passing the data and the selection values like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'tableFilter'
})
export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log(args , 's' , value)
    if(args === 'Checked'){
        return value.filter(x=>x.checked)
    }else if(args === 'NotChecked'){
         return value.filter(x=>!x.checked)
    }else{
      return value
    }
  }

}
```

here is a working model
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wb7ig?embed=1&file=app/table-selection-example.html

Comment: Nice! Works like a charm :-) Thanks